# How to Map Servlet Actions to JSP Path with Annotations?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, tomcat9

I have a simple Maven servlet/jsp application that I deploy to a local Tomcat 9 (via Eclipse). JSP pages are stored under root folder (`src\main\webapp\*.jsp`) which when Maven installs a WAR, they go under the root folder (`MyAppContext\*.jsp` along side `MyAppContext\META-INF\` and `MyAppContext\WEB-INF\`).

The servlets' URL patterns are annotated for each servlet, e.g. `/doactionone`, `/doactiontwo`, etc. Most servlets perform the dispatching to various JSP pages, but I do have a direct anchor link on one.

I wanted to move these JSP pages into their own respective directory, so I moved them to `src\main\webapp\jsp\*.jsp` folder, and when the Maven install is run, they get placed under `MyAppContext\jsp\`.

The only entry I have in `web.xml` is a welcome file that after relocating the JSP files, it points to `jsp\doactionone.jsp` which loads that corresponding JSP page. This page contains a simple form:

```
<form action="doactionone" method="post">
    ...
    <a href="jsp/doactiontwo.jsp">
    <input type="submit" />...
</form>
```

The submission on this page actually calls the right servlet (the one defined with `doactionone` URL pattern). I also have a link that takes the user to the second page (`doactiontwo.jsp`).

However, when I navigate to that second page via this link, which has another simple form (see below), and perform the submission (post), I see in browser's debugging that the URL request is `http://localhost:8080/MyAppContext/jsp/doactiontwo` which, for obvious reason, would return a 404 status (and get no hit to this servlet's `doPost()` (or `doGet()`) methods either).

```
<form action="doactiontwo" method="post">
    ...
    <input type="submit" />...
</form>
```

If I try to modify the second servlet's URL pattern to `/jsp/doactiontwo`, I can hit the servlet, but when `doactiontwo` actually dispatches/forwards the request after processing to the first servlet (`doactionone`) with:

```
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("doactionone.jsp");
rd.forward(request, response);
```

when it gets loaded, when hover over the URL on the first page that initially was pointing to the second JSP page (`<a href="jsp/doactiontwo.jsp">`), now actually points to:

```
jsp/jsp/doactiontwo.jsp
```

The funny part is that the source code of doactionone.jsp still shows it as `jsp/doactiontwo.jsp`, but hovering over it shows `http://localhost:8080/MyAppContext/jsp/jsp/doactiontwo`, and when clicked, it obviously results in 404 status.

Can somebody explain why, first of all, the submission on the second JSP page requires the servlet to have a pattern of `/jsp/doactiontwo` to work rather than `/doactiontwo`? And is there a way around to avoid appending `/jsp` to the URL pattern?

And second, why when the second servlet processes the request and dispatches/forwards it to the first page, the URL now contains two `jsp/`'s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your design to allow the controllers, a.k.a. Servlets, to drive your application. In this particular case, use the URL Pattern of second Servlet (`doactiontwo`) in place of you link:

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = { "doactiontwo" }
public class DoActionTwoServlet extends HttpServlet { /* ... */ }

<form action="doactionone" method="post">
    ...
    <a href="doactiontwo"> <!-- This should match your second servlet's URL pattern -->
    <input type="submit" />...
</form>
```

Now, since the default method when anchor link is invoked is `GET`, you need to overwrite `DoActionTwoServlet`'s `doGet()` method, and forward those requests to an actual `doactiontwo.jsp`:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
  throws ServletException, IOException  {

     RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("jsp/doactiontwo.jsp");
     rd.forward(request, response);
}
```

Comment: thanks, that works. I think the `urlPattern` should be `urlPatterns`

Comment: hello, great answer. please, is there a way to map the request to a specific action instead of a whole class, is it necessary to create a new class for every form/url? thanx